# Don't see local disk storage Athens

Tags: go, package, offline

I need a guide how to install athens for installing previously downloaded go packages. I have created a binary file from athens https://github.com/athensresearch/athens and configure .toml with path to local storage, also change the storage parameter to [disk
] then i downloaded a directory of random package from github unzipped it and place in this Storage folder. But when i try to make request to localhost:port[file_path] it return 404 error. so it don't see my folder. Where is the trouble? who has already worked with athens, can you consult me please.